# Capture directory & contents, Rotate for only the last three days

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, logrotate

Our current backup approach requires us to capture a Tomcat directory, and all it's contents.  The rationale is the backup makes redeployment easier in the event of a disaster.

It was rotating based on the day number, so we'd have a rolling week of backups.  Problem is that these are eating too much diskspace, and we really don't need that much history.

I looked at [logrotate](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html), but it seems to be set for specific log files.  Is there some way of making logrotate capture a directory & contents, providing three rolling days history?  Or is there a better alternative?

Comment: +1 for being the SQL guru :)  Glad to see you on SU!

Comment: sorry about the typo in my command, fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had similar requirements.  My solution was backup a daily backup to a dir, then prune based on date.

```
find /path/to/backups/ -name 'tomcat*.tar.bz2' -atime +3 -mtime +3 -exec rm {} \;
DATE=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')
tar -C /path/to/tomcat/root -cjvf /path/to/backups/tomcat-${DATE}.tar.bz2 .
```

Obviously, put this in cron.  Run once daily.

Comment: +1: I'm getting a "tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive"

Comment: @OMG: you must specify the files you want to backup at the end of the `tar` command line..

Comment: @lorenzog: I want the contents of the entire directory.

Comment: @OMG then just put `.` (the current directory) or the name of the directory if you're one level up.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the `-u` option of `tar` (updates only newer files), and compressing the file every week?

Also think about this: is really disk space such a big issue? Given how little hard drives cost lately, is an hour of your time worth doing this compared to the cost of buying a TB of space and forgetting about it?

Comment: It's a co-located server, this is a VM.  I can't throw in the drive, has to go through channels.  The reality is that after a day, the data is out of sync with the database anyway.